# ignore % character in href

Tags: latex, special-characters, href

I want to use `\href` to shorten an url.
My current document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=Blue]{hyperref}
...
\begin{document}
\href{https://www.flickr.com/search/?safe_search=1&license=2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C9&dimension_search_mode=min&height=640&width=640&media=photos}{https://www.flickr.com/search/?license=2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C9}
\end{document}
```

My desired output is an url `https://www.flickr.com/search/?license=2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C9` that, when clicked on, links to the long link.

Currently, latex interprets the `%` in the url as the start of comments and doesn't show the url at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it in TeXstudio on Ubuntun and it seems to work, when you put a backslash in front of the %. `% => \%`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=Blue]{hyperref}
...
\begin{document}
\href{https://www.flickr.com/search/?safe_search=1&license=2\%2C3\%2C4\%2C5\%2C6\%2C9&dimension_search_mode=min&height=640&width=640&media=photos}{https://www.flickr.com/search/?license=2\%2C3\%2C4\%2C5\%2C6\%2C9}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. Tried commenting out the `%` myself, but only between the first pair of brackets... So replacing them everywhere is the trick. Was hoping for some sort of smart solution, like the `url` package which is smart enough to recognize the `%` as being part of the url, but maybe this is as smart as it gets.